# How to create an overview for a GTD implementation in emacs org mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I am implementing a [GTD](https://gettingthingsdone.com) system in org-mode. I use tags for headings to signify various levels of "stuff". Primarily, I use "Goal" and "Project" tags to differentiate between a Goal (which is not a todo) and a project (which is a todo and goes through status changes). Projects can be children of Goals but the opposite is not true. Projects can exist without a Goal.

I use multiple files in 2/3 directories (which are scanned for org files and are added as agenda targets).

What I would like to achieve is a view which presents an overview of goals and projects as a hierarchical view as following

- Goals

  - Goal 1

    - Project 1
    - Project 2
  - Goal 2
  - ...
- Projects

  - Project 1
  - Project 2

Is there a way (preferably agenda view) to generate this?

Comment: I have followed https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-custom-agenda-commands.html to create other gtd views (e.g. context action lists).

Comment: Have you looked at the [Org mode and GTD](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-gtd-etc.html) page on Worg?

Comment: @NickD, yes, see the link in my comments above. I couldn’t find a way to achieve what I want.

Comment: You might be interested in a [recent org-mode GTD package: org-gtd](https://github.com/Trevoke/org-gtd.el).